# Can't install Transcoder plugin

Tags: plugins, install, composer

Not sure whether I should be posting this here or as a Github issue, but when trying to install NY Studio's [Transcoder plugin](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-transcoder/), I get:

> Composer output: Package "craftcms/vue-asset" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
> Package "yiisoft/yii2-shell" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Updating dependencies
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>
> The requested package nystudio107/craft-seomatic (locked at 3.3.17, required as ^3.3.18) is satisfiable by nystudio107/craft-seomatic[3.3.17] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>
> Running update with --no-dev does not mean require-dev is ignored, it
> just means the packages will not be installed. If dev requirements are
> blocking the update you have to resolve those problems.

composer.json looks like this:

```
{
  "require": {
    "barrelstrength/sprout-fields": "^3.8.3",
    "craftcms/cms": "^3.4.24",
    "craftcms/redactor": "^2.6.1",
    "dukt/analytics": "^4.0",
    "nystudio107/craft-seomatic": "3.3.18",
    "nystudio107/craft-typogrify": "^1.1",
    "ostark/craft-async-queue": "^1.3.3",
    "putyourlightson/craft-blitz": "^3.6.5",
    "topshelfcraft/wordsmith": "^3.2.0",
    "verbb/cp-nav": "^3.0.13.1",
    "verbb/field-manager": "^2.1.8",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "modules\\": "modules/",
      "modules\\exifReturn\\": "modules/"
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "platform": {
      "php": "7.0"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ]
  },
  "repositories": [
    { "type": "composer", "url": "https://packagist.phpcomposer.com"}
  ]
}
```

Has anyone else had this problem and how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing it to this:

```json
    "nystudio107/craft-seomatic": "^3.3.0",
```

Comment: Same except error now says `The requested package nystudio107/craft-seomatic (locked at 3.3.17, required as 3.3.0)`

Comment: Do I need to delete `composer.lock` and reinstall?

Comment: That's what I did and was able to install. 